# Как вывести ссылки постраничной навигации с точками?

Tags: php, пагинация

Каким образом вывести ссылки пагинации вот такого вида:

1 2 3 ... [6] ... 9 10

Додумался только вот до этого:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++): ?>
   <a href="?page=<?= $i ?>"><?= $i ?></a>
<?php endfor ?>
```

$pages — количество страничек.

Т. е. нужно, чтобы было видно ссылки на первую страницу, последнюю и текущую (активную), ну и чтобы строка со ссылками всегда была одинаковой длины и не увеличивалась.

Comment: [если здесь](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+php) что то не получится то обратитесь сюда с провальными примерами